# Valid XHTML: "itemscope" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C). I have the following error:

"itemscope" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

Which corresponds to this code:

```
<body class="innerpage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Physician">

<body class="innerpage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Physician">
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Leads -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/face.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Life is to short to make every page valid, just relax

Comment: Do you have to use the XHTML doctype, or can you switch to HTML5?

Comment: Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, because http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd knows nothing about those attributes (itemscope, itemtype). You can convince yourself by downloading [that file](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd) to your computer and trying to find (Ctrl+F) the words `itemscope` or `itemtype` within that document. You will get 0 results.

So basically, You’ve got 2 choices starting from here:

1. If You want to continue using `itemscope` and `itemtype` attributes You
   have to switch to HTML5 doctype, then your document would look like
   as follows:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body class="innerpage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Physician">
   <p>Content</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

This will result in:

`This document was successfully checked as HTML5!`

2. If You need to preserve XHTML Document Type Definition, then You have to switch from microdata to RDF and Your document will look the following:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <title>Title</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   </head>
   <body class="innerpage" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Physician">
   <p>Content</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

This will result in:

`This document was successfully checked as -//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN!`

Comment: You will need to indent each line of code with eight spaces if the code is embedded in a list. I've fixed the formatting for you.

Comment: I had edited your post already - there was no need to do anything else. "Rollback" means undoing an edit altogether.